# How can I overload a method with @QueryParam in Jersey/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, overloading, query-string

I would like to overload a method with the @QueryParam but everytime I try to execute this code it throws:

```
SEVERE: Exception occurred when intialization
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
```

My code is:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getText(@QueryParam("PID") String pid)
{
  return pid;
}

@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getText(@QueryParam("PID") String pid, @QueryParam("NAME") String name)
{
  return pid + name;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No can be.

It's ok in java, but the thing about it is - from the servlet side - jersey needs to map each url to some function in your class.

What you can do is, of course, separate it into 2 methods, or build one method that checks the parameters and does the right logic.

Comment: +1 Methods must have a unique path. Query params are not considered part of the path. You could try using `@PathParam` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the rest endpoint in terms of what request/query parameters are present in the request.

Here's the answer that solved my use case: create two method for same url pattern with different arguments