# Java (Jersey) handling GET method requests with and without parameters

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, uri

I am trying to send some parameters through a GET method from a console app to a web service. The code I have provided below works when both ends "agree", as in both the console app and webservice have the same amount of parameter or none.

I need to be able to handle the GET request depending on the number and which parameters are sent. For example I use 3 parameters but at times I might send only 1, 2 or none at all and depending on that, I will call the appropriate function, not listofstuff() all the time. How can I do, manage those scenarios, if possible at all?

webservice code:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String returnList(
        @QueryParam("id_nr") String sid_nr,
        @QueryParam("name") String name,
        @QueryParam("value") String svalue)
{
        int id_nr=Integer.parseInt(sid_nr);
        int value=Integer.parseInt(svalue);

        return listofstuff(id_nr,name,value).toString();
}
```

console application code:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());
int id_nr=1;
String name="Ion";
int value=1;
System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("hello").queryParam("id_nr", id_nr).queryParam("name", name).queryParam("value", value).request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(Response.class).toString());
System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("hello").queryParam("id_nr", id_nr).queryParam("name", name).queryParam("value", value).request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));
```

Comment: You can't overload methods with `QueryParam`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030045/how-can-i-overload-a-method-with-queryparam-in-jersey-spring

Answer (score 0):

```
@DefaultValue("0")
```

Adding that in front of the  @QueryParam() was a workaround. Not exactly what I was looking for but I can work with that,

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. You send null values in your `QueryParam` and check them in your code. What's the issue then?